# How do you accommodate iOS device's lack of a physical back button when developing in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So Android and Windows Phone devices both have physical back buttons, while iOS devices do not.

How do you accommodate iOS device's lack of a physical back button when developing in Bootstrap?  Do you just have to manually include a back button in the nav no matter what?  If so, doesn't this limitation sort of demote Bootstrap, so to speak, simply because it isn't natively designed to work well with iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be getting confused between what Bootstrap is really there for, and how the iOS browser works.

For starters, Safari in iOS (last time I used it anyway) does have a back button. A browser without a back button would be an absolute disaster! It's just hidden when you start using the page

http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/25/show-navigation-buttons-safari-iphone/

Admittedly this is for iOS 7/8 and not 9, and I don't have an iOS 9 device so couldn't comment, but I'm fairly certain it'll have a back button somewhere, although it is a 'soft' button and not an always there button like you get on Android and Windows devices. I think anyone that's been using iOS for any length of time will know how to go back, **things like the Back button are for the browsers to worry about, not you.**

Remember, Bootstrap is, at it's core, a grid system and UI framework, it's not there to be a fully native application, it's for the web. If there was no back button in Safari iOS that would be an issue with Safari, **not** with Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for this- I had Apache Cordova on the brain.